# How to keep a changed python working directory

Tags: python

I'm looking to keep a change in my python working directory; however, when I change the directory with the following code:

```
import os
os.chdir('Path')
```

and exit out of python, the working directory reverts back to the default while attempting to run a script within this working directory.

How do I keep the changed working directory? I'm using a Mac (if that makes a difference). Any help is greatly appreciated for this novice looking to self teach python.

Comment: This isn’t really possible: each process has its own working directory, and can’t change its parent’s (except via invasive, inadvisable means).

Comment: a bad workaround could be to run shell command `cd` within python

Comment: There may be another workaround, depending on what you're ultimately trying to do.  Do you have a separate Python script, and just want to execute from within Terminal from a directory other than the one it's in?

Comment: @mamun: That would launch a new shell and change the new shell's working directory, not the parent shell's working directory.

Comment: What are you really trying to do after changing the working directory ? Are you looking forward to execute a script in the then changed directory ? Are you trying to import a module from there ?  Are you trying to open a file ?

Comment: In a similar situation, I ended up having my script just output the desired folder path to stdout, and made a wrapper alias like `cd $(python ~\my-script.py)`